# Adding contrast and brightness to image in flex

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flash-builder

How can i implement brightness and contrast changes for image in flex

I need to develop a tool for adding brightness or contrast  and reducing it

Comment: Have you tried anything? What's your problem? Displaying image? Applying math formula?

Comment: Need to change brightness and contrast dynamically for image loaded in image component

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use ColorMatrixFilter and assigned below matrix to its matrix property

```
var contrastAdj:ColorMatrixFilter = ColorMatrixFilter(filters.getItemAt(0));
        contrastAdj.matrix = getContrastMatrix(value);

    private static function getContrastMatrix(value:Number):Array
    {

    value /= 100;
    var s: Number = value + 1;
    var o : Number = 128 * (1 - s);
    var m:Array = new Array();
    m = m.concat([s, 0, 0, 0, o]);  // red
    m = m.concat([0, s, 0, 0, o]);  // green
    m = m.concat([0, 0, s, 0, o]);  // blue
    m = m.concat([0, 0, 0, 1, 0]);  // alpha

    return m;
}
```

for brightness matrix use this function

```
private static function getBrightnessMatrix(value:Number):Array
{
                var m:Array = new Array();
                m = m.concat([1, 0, 0, 0, value]);  // red
                m = m.concat([0, 1, 0, 0, value]);  // green
                m = m.concat([0, 0, 1, 0, value]);  // blue
                m = m.concat([0, 0, 0, 1, 0]);      // alpha
                return m;
        }
```

pass values between -100 to 100 to functions.

Comment: you can use Pixel Bender to speed up image manipulation as @Vesper suggested. For a single image i think these functions would be enough.

Answer (score 1):

You might use `flash.geom.ColorTransform` against an image, at least for previewing. If you need to have your image's pixels changed, I'd say use a Pixel Bender shader that will do what you need. Note however, you will need a backup copy should you desire to change the parameters of that shader.